Stripe Manual Capture with Apple Pay
I'm working on a web application where a seller needs to authorize buyer's credit card and then charge it when the item is shipped, I'm using Stripe's PaymentIntent.create with manual capture, first I create a PaymentMethod and then use it to create the PaymentIntent:
async function createPaymentIntent(paymentMethodId) {
  try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: price, // Amount in cents
      currency: 'usd',
      payment_method: paymentMethodId,
      capture_method: 'manual',
    });

    console.log('Payment Intent:', paymentIntent);
    return paymentIntent.client_secret;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating PaymentIntent:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}


Now, I need to add Apple Pay support. Stripe's documentation mentions that authorization and capture with Apple Pay is possible (link), but I couldn't find any detailed instructions on how to actually implement it.
How should I approach adding Apple Pay to this setup to ensure proper authorization and capture flow? Any guidance or advise is greatly appreciated!

After a Apple Pay payment method is saved onto a customer, it will be considered as a card payment. The auth and capture flow will work exactly like a card payment in your code above. For one-time Apple Pay payment, i.e. not creating a payment method first, I'd recommend following the guide here
